# apostrophe-blog - How to implement a next/prev. navigation through articles in show.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I'm quite new on apostrophe-cms but so far I've been able to dig a little around all the main features of this CMS (tutorials, customed widgets, templating,...) and I've successfully integrated the [apostrophe-blog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-blog) plugin and made it work properly as it is demonstrated into the [apostrophe-sandbox](https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-sandbox) project on github.

Yet I couldn't really understand how I could catch the next and prev article's url in order to display a button directly inside the **show.html** file (which is located in the **lib/modules/apostrophe-blog-pages/views/** directory.)

Is there a way to bind to the {{ data.pieces }} available inside the **index.html** (the page that display a blog's articles list, in the same directory) so that I could eventually make a function that would give me an intended {{ data.pieces[n]._url }} corresponding to each articles ?

Cuz so far I could only get a sort of much "local" data.piece in show.html that seems to concerns only each specific article that are displayed on this page.
(for the notice I use {{ data.piece | dump }} nunjuck's property to display it)

Thanks by advance for any helping answers around this topic, and hope I could make my request enoughly explicit to everyone !?

Comment: In the last release of Apostrophe new data.previous and data.next options have been added to the apostrophe-pieces-page in order to use it for example in the case of apostrophe-blog module : http://forum.apostrophecms.org/t/apostrophe-2-29-0-2-30-0-multiple-select-filters-in-manage-pieces-next-and-previous-easy-redis-sessions-accommodations-for-the-workflow-module/215

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the OP, setting the `next: true, previous: true,` options on the `apostrophe-blog-pages` module will make `data.next` and `data.previous` objects available (that can also be limited using a projection property) in the `show.html` template. Those will include the `_url` property to link to.